# c++ codes behave differently with different optimization flag

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

There were four files, `header.h`, `A.cpp`, `B.cpp`, `main.cpp`.

```cpp
// header.h
struct test {
  static inline int get();
};
```

```cpp
// a.cpp
#include "header.h"
int testA() { return test::get(); }
int test::get() { return 0; }
```

```cpp
// b.cpp
#include "header.h"
int testB() { return test::get(); }
int test::get() { return 1; }
```

```cpp
// main.cpp
#include <cstdio>
int testA();
int testB();

int main() {
  printf("%d %d\n", testA(), testB());
}
```

compile with `g++ -o main A.cpp B.cpp main.cpp -O0` the binary outputs two same number, while `-O3` always outputs `0 1`.

In additional, if I add anonymous namespace to `header.h`, i.e.,

```cpp
// header.h
namespace {
struct test {
  static inline int get();
}
}
```

Then `-O0` also gives `0 1`.

But I cannot compile the codes with anonymous namespace, if change `test::get()` to a global function

```cpp
// header.h
namespace {
static inline int test_get(); 
}
// A.cpp
#include "header.h"
int testA() { return test_get(); }
//int test_get() { return 0; }
//namespace { int test_get() { return 0; }
// failed to compile neither with or without namespace
```

Can someone explain the rules here?

Comment: You're violating ODR (one definition rule), that's undefined behavior.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Worse, it's ill-formed. From standard point of view, it's as much C++ as this comment.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen at least your comment would require diagnosis ;)

Comment: The rule is that you're not allowed to provide more than one definition of `test::get`, unless they consist of exactly the same tokens, but nobody's required to tell you if you broke the rule.

Comment: If you have diffent behavior with different settings then the cause is (almost) always a bug (undefined behavior) in your own code.

Comment: There is a whole category of program errors in C++ that I call "[It hurts when I do this](https://a.pinatafarm.com/500x680/483c682d13/bike-fall.jpg)." So don't do that.  Alas, it can be quite a slog to figure out *where* in the code you've hurt yourself.  ODR violations are ones in particular that can be frustrating to track down.

Comment: @Eljay especially if it's ODR breach involving templates with specializations. Code even may appear to work properly except of one case!

Answer (score 5):

> Can someone explain the rules here?

The program is **ill-formed no diagnostic required** as explained below.

From [inline specifier documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline):

> An inline function or variable(since C++17) with external linkage (e.g. not declared static) has the following additional properties:
>
> - **There may be more than one definition of an inline function or variable(since C++17) in the program as long as each definition appears in a different translation unit and** (for non-static inline functions and variables(since C++17)) ***all definitions are identical***. For example, an inline function or an inline variable(since C++17) may be defined in a header file that is included in multiple source files.
>
> **Notes**
>
> If an inline function or variable(since C++17) with external linkage is **defined differently in different translation units, the program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required.**

(emphasis mine)

Since the definitions you've provided are not identical, the program is IFNDR.

Answer (score 2):

In C++ the rule is that you're not allowed to provide definitions of an entity with *same name*, which *differ from each other* in different compilation units, with exclusion of global functions, member functions and global variables which have to have exactly one difinition. In C latter rule applies to types and type aliases until recent standards.

Definitions are same if they are formed by same sequence of lexems after preprocessor had finished its work.

But in case of anonymous namespace you create a unique name for each compilation unit:

```
// included from A.cpp
namespace {
   inline int test_get(); 
}
```

actually would declare a unique name for `A.cpp`, e.g. `_some_internal_namespace_for_a_cpp::test_get`, and

```
// included from B.cpp
namespace {
   inline int test_get(); 
}
```

would declares a unique name for `B.cpp`, e.g. `_some_internal_namespace_for_b_cpp::test_get`. Problem is, you cannot define it! You had to define it at site, inside of same anonymous namespace

```
namespace {
   inline int test_get() { return 0; }
}
```

Which strictly is equivalent of

```
   static inline int test_get() { return 0; }
```

Comment: thx i got it, and the remained question is, why its allowed to define a struct inside anonymous namespace and then implement it's member function outside the namespace, while a simple function cant?

Comment: @Yuxai I would recommend asking a new separate question for that part of the question. One question per post is recommended. One person might know the answer to one part of the question but not the other. So one question per post is advised. Feel free to ask a separate question for the anonymous namespace part.

Comment: @Yuxai  you have defintion of `test_get(); `  somewhere else, but you declare it as internal linkage (see, it is an equivalent of `static`), so it isn't available inside of  `testA` function. A static member function got external linkage